# How do I do a multiple insert in laravel 5.5?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5

I want to do a multiple insert in my Laravel project but I don't know how to do it. Do I need to loop it or there are any other method to do it? I'm a bit confused. I am using querybuilder.

Controller code.

```
if($request->smsn == 'on'){
            $events->smsnotify = 1;

            $numbers = \DB::table('users')
            ->where('school_id', '=', $sid->school_id)
            ->where('role', '=', $request->group_id)
            ->select('phone','name')
            ->get();

            dd($numbers);


            $sms = DB::table('sms')->insert([
                'user_id' => $sid->id,
                'school_id' => $sid->school_id,
                'msg' => 'New Event '. $request->name,
                'mobile_number' =>  $numbers,
                'name' => 'Sample',
                'isSend' => 1
            ]);



        }
```

dump result

```
Collection {#552 ▼
  #items: array:5 [▼
    0 => {#550 ▼
      +"phone": "+63 (928) 206-5706"
      +"name": "Ayden Kutch"
    }
    1 => {#568 ▼
      +"phone": "(0817) 447-1492"
      +"name": "Ruthie Quigley"
    }
    2 => {#567 ▼
      +"phone": "+63 (920) 203-3874"
      +"name": "Alaina O'Kon"
    }
    3 => {#569 ▶}
    4 => {#570 ▶}
  ]
}
```

I want to insert it in my `sms` table like this format

```
+----+---------+---------------+---------------+--------+------------+------------+-----------+-------------+
| id | user_id | msg           | mobile_number | isSend | created_at | updated_at | school_id | name        |
+----+---------+---------------+---------------+--------+------------+------------+-----------+-------------+
|  8 |      13 | New Event    |     123456     |      1 | NULL       | NULL       |         2 | Ayden Kutch |
+----+---------+---------------+---------------+--------+------------+------------+-----------+-------------+
```

In every name and number. It generates another row.

Comment: you can use collection as an array: `foreach($numbers as $rec) {/* insert rec here */}`, is that what you're asking about?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do multiple insert queries in a loop, or a single insert query with an array or arrays, but you will need to build that array first.

```
$data = [];

foreach ($numbers as $number) {
    $data[] = [
        'user_id' => $sid->id,
        'school_id' => $sid->school_id,
        'msg' => 'New Event',
        'mobile_number' =>  $number->phone,
        'name' => $number->name,
        'isSend' => 1
    ];
}

DB::table('sms')->insert($data);
```

This builds an array of multiple records to be inserted together.

> "You may even insert several records into the table with a single call to `insert` by passing an array of arrays. Each array represents a row to be inserted into the table"

[Laravel 5.5 Docs - Query Builder - Inserts](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/queries#inserts)

Comment: are you sure? probably you need to use insert inside the loop?

Comment: @AnatoliyR yes I am sure

Comment: just asking, Lara is my primary framework, but I never did bulk inserts this way

Comment: it is basically the only way to do bulk inserts without building the insert statement yourself ... as a single statement

Comment: definitely it is... unless you run raw query for your risk

Comment: @AnatoliyR you can build the insert query yourself with parameters, so no risk at all ... that is what the bound parameters are for   `DB::insert('INSERT into TABLE ("field1", "field2") values (?, ?), (?, ?), (?, ?)', $parameters);`   it is what the query builder will end up doing anyway ... prepared statements are everyone's best friend :)

Comment: I think it's worth mentioning that it would be a good idea to enclose this in a transaction too.

Answer (score 2):

**This Work for me**

```
$value = array();

foreach ($users as $user) {
$value = array(
    'user_id' => $user->id,
    'name' => $user->name,
    'mobile_number' =>  $user->phone,
);
DB::table('users')->insert($data);
}
```